# Does Orochimaru need a host?

Tags: naruto

After the Hokage the third took his arms, Orochimaru needed a new body for himself. Later, shortly before Sasuke killed him, this body was rejecting him, so he wanted to take Sasukes body as his new host.
In his fight against Sasuke, he abandons his body and appears as a huge snake. And here's the question: Does Orochimaru need a host at all, and why? Or can he stay as a snake for longer time?

Comment: ohh I so wish I could spoil this!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you remember when Orochimaru had been discovered by the Third Hokage while he was experimenting on people<sup>1</sup>? That's what he was researching: a technique for immortality.

It's called [不屍転生 (Fushi Tensei)](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Living_Corpse_Reincarnation) or literally *Living Corpse Reincarnation* and allows Orochimaru to transfer his soul into his  prey's body and take possession of it.

He researches this because as he says, he wants to learn all the existing techniques, but since that is impossible for a person with a normal lifespan, he develops this technique in order to have more time.

The problem with this technique is that each host lasts around 3 years, so he needs to find another one after that. If he could find a perfect container he could stay in it for a full lifetime, but he would need to find another one again anyways after that.

<sup>1: Chapter 122 in Naruto, Volume 14</sup>

Comment: So he *could* stay without a host?

Comment: @looper I have no hard evidence for that, but I doubt it. I can look for more info if you want, but I am not sure there is something canon (not sure there isn't either, though).

Comment: I guess that's good :). Maybe I'll find something new when I read the more recent chapters.

Comment: @looper Ok, later I'll do some more search. In case I find something, I'll notify you.

Comment: But even if he could stay a snake forever what's the point of that?  He wants to master the jitsu however with no arms he can't. It's noteworthy to note that when he's fighting Sasuke Sasuke insults him by saying, "Look at what you've become.  Why would I let you inhabit me?"  He's an abomination with no arms.

Answer (score 3):

If understand it correctly Orochimaru can stay in his snake form for a longer time. But staying in that form has lots of disadvantages, since he cannot use any of his jutsu (no hands). Since his goal is to master all jutsu in this world, it is very inconvenient for him to remain in that state.