# What or who can kill Orochimaru's life force?

Tags: naruto

Where is Orochimaru's life force bounded? Why doesn't he die like others?

1. First at Orochimaru's den, Sasuke tried to kill Orochimaru while Orochimaru tried to take over Sasuke's body.
2. Then later in the manga, during the fight between Sasuke and Itachi, Orochimaru was revealed to be partly present inside Sasuke, where Itachi dealt with him.
3. Now, after Edo, Itachi and Sasuke beat Kabuto. Sasuke was able to pull out Orochimaru from Kabuto.

Why is that Orochimaru can survive in different distributed forms? How is his life force immortal?

(Sasori was able to survive using puppets for his real body, but the life force was bounded to his heart, so when the heart died, so did Sasori.)

What or who can kill him permanently? (except the author)

PS : I did read the question at [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2403/does-orochimaru-need-a-host) but what I am interested in knowing is different.

Comment: Honestly, if you want a simpler explanation, the curse seals work like a horcrux from HP. A piece of his soul, or life force, is bound to whomever carries his seal, that's why Anko could tell when he was close by. So Orochimaru can only die after all his soul portions have been expunged, and killed from whatever curse seals he's planted.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's get the facts right:

1. Sasuke did not kill Orochimaru. Orochimaru entered Sasuke's mind and tried to take it over, but failed. Hence he got "sealed" inside.
2. That's why Orochimaru continued to live inside of Sasuke, after exhausting all of his chakra, Sasuke failed to restrain Orochimaru and he broke free (only for Itachi to permanently seal him again).
3. Orochimaru's Cursed Seal allows him to inject his **[snake sage chakra](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_Mode#Snake_Sage_Mode)**. That allows him (much like Minato and Kushina did with Naruto), to have part of his consciousness sealed inside of the people he gives his cursed mark to.

   Due to that fact, Orochimaru's consciousness lives inside of **Anko**, and after supplying it with some flesh from Kabuto (who contained Orochimaru's and Hashirama's cells), the consciousness part was able to retain control and a body. Also, absorbing all of his own cells from Kabuto, he managed to get the information he needed, as well as his life-force, to recover.

Actually, I'm pretty sure that if he's *killed* now, he'll die (unless he has some backup copy/cells/whatever hidden elsewhere, waiting for the next sucker to discover and awaken).

Comment: He did what Voldemort failed to do ;)